# Where and how does WordPress store and use its plugin and hook information?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

When WordPress installs a plugin, where does it keep the fact of a hook/plugins existence?  For example, [wp-includes/plugin.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/plugin.php)

I can see `do_action`, but I'm not familiar enough to know how WP loads its plugins.  Does it have the hook name in the database along with the new plugged in hook name?  I looked in wp_options, but did not anything.

Answer (score 4):

WordPress stores the currently active plugins in the options table under the key `active_plugins`.

Hooked actions and filters aren't stored anywhere, plugins must add their hooks on every request, otherwise they don't exist.

Comment: I didn't put that I saw active_plugins, sorry.  But what I didn't know is that all the plugins are called with each request.  Doesn't that make things very slow?

Comment: well sure, there is some overhead to including files, but slower than what alternative exactly? it ultimately depends on what the plugin does. there are other methods to get far greater performance gains than worrying about a few hundredths of a millisecond here and there.

Comment: I guess you have to store the information somewhere, db, xml file, or whatever.

Comment: Is registering a hook or plugin the same as adding a callback?

Comment: you can invoke custom hooks that other code can hook a callback to, via `do_action` or `apply_filters`. when you `add_action` or `add_filter`, you're registering a callback for that action or filter hook.